# What is the meaning of the phrase "the 'one ring' of something"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have encountered the phrase in the following context

> This tool is the 'one ring' of static analysis tools in Python

Comment: For future reference, please provide more details, not just the one sentence, in case the meaning is not as clear.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Tolkien: Lord of the Rings:

> Three Rings for the Elven-kings under the sky,
>
> Seven for the Dwarf-lords in their halls of stone,
>
> Nine for Mortal Men doomed to die,
>
> One for the Dark Lord on his dark throne.
>
> One Ring to rule them all. One Ring to find them,
>
> One Ring to bring them all and in the darkness bind them.

To be true to Tolkien the 'one ring' should have the power to control the lesser rings, I doubt that will be true of this Static Analysis Tool. More likely the author simply means **most powerful** or **most desirable**, precious.

Comment: @djna thanks for your answer. After reading it, I'm most certain that the intention was true to Tolkein, since the tool mentioned in the sentence is one that acts like a union of set of many other powerful tools.

Comment: http://imgur.com/gallery/44GIbzG

Comment: Cf. "holy grail"

Comment: The "one ring" implies not just that it is the **most powerful** or **most desirable**, but also that it has all the features of its competitors and more.  That is, "Product Y might do _this_ well, and Product Z might do _that_ well, but Product X is the **one ring** and does _this_ **and** _that_ well."

Comment: @HarrisonPaine I wouldn't have picked up on that meaning, and don't see how it is implied. Do you have an example of it meaning that, or a reference, or something?

Comment: It is a bit of a mixed metaphor, if one thinks about it, though; the One Ring was essentially cursed by the lord of darkness. I've used some libraries I might describe that way...

Comment: @WilliamKappler I was thinking the same thing. The static analysis tool that will eventually turn evil and need chucked into a volcano. There's also the whole thing with the ringwraiths: If you (say that you) use this tool (on the internet), tortured angry people will try to hurt you. Which isn't that untrue of various dev tools as it is…

Comment: @DCShannon Well, in Lord of the Rings, it's "one ring to rule them all", not "one ring to work in tandem with the others".  The implication is that if you have the One Ring, you don't need any of the others.